# Default deposit on a percentage of the total cart amount with exceptions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, fee

I was looking for a way to add a deposit on the TOTAL Cart Amount on a Woocommerce site (rather than just adding a deposit to each product line item).

I found the answer to this ingenious thread here: [Deposit based on a percentage of total cart amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616367/deposit-based-on-a-percentage-of-total-cart-amount)

Here's the code I ended up using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'booking_deposit_calculation' ); 
function booking_deposit_calculation( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    ## Set HERE your negative percentage (to remove an amount from cart total)
    $percent = -.50; // 50% off (negative)

    // Get cart subtotal excluding taxes
    $cart_subtotal = $cart_object->subtotal_ex_tax;
    // or for subtotal including taxes use instead:
    // $cart_subtotal = $cart_object->subtotal;

    ## ## CALCULATION ## ##
    $calculated_amount = $cart_subtotal * $percent;

    // Adding a negative fee to cart amount (excluding taxes)
    $cart_object->add_fee( __('Deposit calculation', 'woocommerce'), $calculated_amount, false );

}
```

This creates a default of 50% deposit for every product on the Cart and Checkout page. Brilliant! (Using CSS, I was then able to style the descriptions on the front-end.)

However, I have a few products (one product category) on which I don't want to force this deposit.

So, here's my question:

**How can I tweak the code to continue to enforce a default deposit but exclude the deposit from one product category (or the products in this category if I cannot exclude an entire category)?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the hooked function below, you will have to set an array of products Ids or *(and)* product categories, to exclude them. If you don't use one of them you can set a blank array like for example `$product_categories = array();` …

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_deposit_calculation', 10, 1 );
function custom_deposit_calculation( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Define the product IDs to exclude
    $product_ids = array( 37, 25, 50 );
    // Define the product categories to exclude (can be IDs, slugs or names)
    $product_categories = array( 'clothing' );
    $amount_to_exclude_with_tax = 0;

    // Iterating through cart items
    foreach ( $cart_object->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        // If condition match we get the sum of the line item total (excl. tax) 
        if( in_array( $cart_item['product_id'], $product_ids ) || has_term( $product_categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
            $amount_to_exclude_with_tax += $cart_item['line_total'];
            // OR replace by (for tax inclusion)
            // $amount_to_exclude_with_tax += $cart_item['line_tax'] + $cart_item['line_total'];
    }

    ## Set HERE your negative percentage (to remove an amount from cart total)
    $percent = -0.5; // 50% off (negative)

    // Get cart subtotal excluding taxes
    $cart_subtotal = $cart_object->subtotal_ex_tax - $amount_to_exclude_with_tax;
    // or for subtotal including taxes use instead:
    // $cart_subtotal = $cart_object->subtotal;

    ## ## CALCULATION ## ##
    $calculated_amount = $cart_subtotal * $percent;

    if( $calculated_amount != 0){
        // Adding a negative fee to cart amount (Including taxes)
        $cart_object->add_fee( __('Deposit calculation', 'woocommerce'), $calculated_amount, true );
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested on WooCommerce 3 and works.