# Deposit on backordered cart items in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I've taken this code from another post and basically this code is trying to force the cart price with a discount.

What I want to do is force the discount only if the product is on backorder. So if product is on backorder, the client can order this item which leads to a deposit calculation in the cart.

From [Deposit based on a percentage of total cart amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42616367/deposit-based-on-a-percentage-of-total-cart-amount/42617383#42617383) 2nd code snippet answer, I have tried to make code changes to get a specific discount on backordered cart items.

The original code works fine as it's, but how to make it work only for backordered items?

I tried several days now using for example `$product->is_on_backorder( 1 )` but I can't get it to work. How to get backordered items total amount in cart?

I know it's an easy solution, but I have tried several solutions and can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:** To make that for backordered items only, you will use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'calculated_deposit_discount_on_backorders' );
function calculated_deposit_discount_on_backorders( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    ## Set HERE your negative percentage (to remove an amount from cart total)
    $percent = -.80; // 80% off (negative)

    $backordered_amount = 0;

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
            $backordered_amount = $cart_item['line_total'] + $cart_item['line_tax'];
        }
    }

    ## ## CALCULATION ## ##
    $calculated_amount = $backordered_amount * $percent;

    // Adding a negative fee to cart amount (Including taxes)
    $cart->add_fee( __('Deposit calculation', 'woocommerce'), $calculated_amount, true );

}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! Thank you for the fast response and solution. :)